# Coding Operation research algorithms

Tags: linear-programming, reference-request, books

Can you suggest good books to refer regarding coding operation research algorithms like transportation algorithm, assignment algorithm etc
What are the best practices for coding those algorithms

Comment: Hello. The term "operation research algorithms" implies a wide set of alternatives. But, as a starting point, I would suggest this one https://juliabook.chkwon.net/book.